# In Eclipse: How to set default VM arguments for a new server runtime?

Tags: eclipse, server, jboss, jvm-arguments

I quite often have to update the server runtime in Eclipse's Servers View. For this, I import the standalone JBoss installation into the Servers View via:

New -> Server -> Red Hat Jboss EAP 7.x ...

Now, this server does not have enough heap space configured, so I have to open the Launch Configuration where the default VM arguments are defined. Then I change the heap from -Xmx512m to something like -Xmx4g.

I would have suspected this configuration to be in the jboss installation somewhere, but I have switched every occurence of -Xmx512m in every file to -Xmx4g without luck.

How can I change the default value to be -Xmx4g without changing it manually every time I have to import a new server runtime?

Comment: Up to my knowledge you can't change the default of something you haven't installed yet. Recommendation: execute JBoss using a script with your VM flags set.

Answer (score 0):

In Jboss, JVM configurations are placed under *"Jboss Directory/bin/standalone.conf*" (if your are running in standalone mode) .

Inside standalone.conf , you can find the JVM startup config

```
#
#Specify options to pass to the Java VM.
#
if [ "x$JAVA_OPTS" = "x" ]; then
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=$JBOSS_MODULES_SYSTEM_PKGS -Djava.awt.headless=true"
else

echo "JAVA_OPTS already set in environment; overriding default settings with values: $JAVA_OPTS"
fi
```

You need to modify "JAVA_OPTS="-Xms64m -Xmx512m " to your requirements .

Hope this suits your need . Thanks.